# Piping a response into another response in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, pipe

Assume I have an HTTP request (req2) inside another HTTP request (req1) in ExpressJS. What I receive as the req2's response is generating a file download process using mongoDB bucket.openDownloadStreamByName (res2).

```
bucket.openDownloadStreamByName(filename)
      .on('data', function(chunk) {
        res2.write(chunk);
      })
      .on('error', function(error) {
        res2.sendStatus(404);
      })
      .on('end', function() {
        res2.end();
      });
```

What I need is piping res2 exactly to res1 so file download stream works for res1 too. Is it possible in nodeJS?

Comment: For every `res2` statement, create a duplicate, like `res1.write(chunk); res2.write(chunk);`.

Comment: res1 and res2 are not on same thread. res2 is a response of HTTP request. Therfore res1 has not any access to code block above. All we have is response of nodejs http.request related to res2.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Can you share more of your code?